# Flutter: How can i add native caller screen and want to play prerecorded audio when someone receive a call

Tags: android, ios, callkit, android-connectionservice

I want to implement a native caller screen and want to connect it with FCM. But, On the caller screen, I want to play audio that is attached to my app. Is that possible?

I was trying [flutter callKeep](https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep). but it didn't work properly on android 11 and also didn't manage to play prerecorded audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I found I need a VoIP service. so I change my mind in that way